# Lambda Expression Not Working (C++) (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, generics, lambda, clang++

I have ran into a problem with using lambda expressions in Visual Studio Code. When using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct Person{
    string name;
    int age;

    Person(string n, int a){
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Person& p1){
        os << "(" << p1.name << ", " << p1.age << "), ";
        return os;
    }
};

template <class T, size_t N>
void printA(std::array<T, N> arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){cout << arr[i] << ", ";}
    cout << endl;
};

int main(){
    array<Person, 5> people = {Person("Dean", 20), Person("Aleksandra", 21), Person("Anna Marie", 47), Person("Matthew", 47), Person("Jaynalyn", 25)};

    sort(people.begin(), people.end(), [](const Person& p1, const Person& p2){p1.age < p2.age;});
    printA(people);
}
```

I receive this error code:

```
genericsort.cpp:30:40: error: expected expression
    sort(people.begin(), people.end(), [](const Person& p1, const Person& p2){p1.age < p2.age;});
                                       ^
1 error generated.
```

I also think it might be worth mentioning that I was able to compile and run this code in xCode and it also worked in replit.

I have seen some other threads saying that this may be a result of me using a pre-C++11 compiler, but my Visual Studio Code cppStandard = "c++17". If you have any insight into how I can fix this, it would be much appreciated! Thanks

I have tried to update g++ and clang via my macOS terminal, and these both show that they are up to date. I have tried to change the cppStandard to c++11 and it still outputs the same error code. I am really just not sure if this is a problem with my Visual Studio Code not being set up properly.

Comment: It doesn't matter what is in your VSCode settings, what is important is what command you use to compile the code. Especially on macOS you need to pass something like `-std=c++17` during compilation

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are actually compiling with C++17?

Also the comparator parameter of sort expects a signature

```
[](const Person& p1, const Person& p2) -> bool ..
```

But you are supplying it with:

```
[](const Person& p1, const Person& p2) -> void ...
```

Likely because you are missing a `return` statement in your lambda expression:

```
sort(people.begin(), people.end(), [](const Person& p1, const Person& p2){ return p1.age < p2.age; }); // Return goes here
```

As to why your code compiled and ran on clang and xCode, I have no clue. Maybe you haven't made the mistake there? Either way, it should compile now.

Comment: I am using code runner to run the code. But yeah in terms of running this code in xCode, it was exactly similar to this code that I have provided above. How can I check to make sure that I am compiling with c++17?